# Printing a customized Array in php

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, range, if-statement

How to get this code to work? The code organizes array2 prints the first 2 results in array2 then prints the rest of the array below. "Some lines are from python".

```
$array2 = array(101040=>"one",101060=>"two",102040=>"three",102020=>"four"); 
$array1 = new ArrayObject();
$array1->append("101040");
$array1->append("101060");
$array1->append("102020");
      if (strlen($array1)==0)
       {
          print "Array is empty.";
       }
else if(strlen($array1)>2)
    {
    $array1->asort();
    print ($array2[$array1[0]]);
    print ($array2[$array1[1]]);
    for a in range(int(strlen($array1))-2);
    print ($array2[$array1[a+2]]);
   }
 else
       {
        $array1->asort();
        for a in range(strlen($array1)):
        print($array2[$array1[a]]);
       }
```

I would like this to work in php.

Comment: Why don't you just add expected result ?

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
<?php
    $array1 = array("101040", "101060", "102020");
    $array2 = array(101040 => "one", 101060 => "two", 102040 => "three", 102020 => "four"); 
    if (count($array1) == 0) {
      print "Array is empty.";
    } else if(count($array1) > 2) {
        asort($array1);
        print ($array2[$array1[0]]);
        print ($array2[$array1[1]]);
        for( $i = 0, $max = count($array1)-2; $i < $max; $i++) {
            print ($array2[$array1[$i+2]]);
        }
    } else {
        asort($array1);
        for( $i = 0, $max = count($array1); $i < $max; $i++) {
            print ($array2[$array1[$i]]);
        }
    }
?>
```

Outputs `onetwofour`. [View the test run on codepad.org](http://codepad.org/T4UMPFY7).

Comment: `s/strlen/count/` to be valid.

Comment: Oops, forgot that one. Thanks @cbuckley :)

Comment: I need it to sort the numbers in array1 low to high e.g. sort($array1); this will not work when I append values to array1.

Comment: Not quite sure I follow. :)